# MySQL Workbench Migration: MSSQL to MySQL - Incorrect String Value

Tags: mysql, .net, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I have a .NET 6 application that is currently backed by MSSQL database, that is maintained by Entity Framework using a Model First approach. I am trying to migrate it to use a MySQL database backend, for a variety of reasons.

I have installed MySQL Locally (Windows) to start exploring and getting it working. I can migrate the schema easily enough (With either MySQL Workbench or using EF) but migrating the data is proving to be a little tricky.

Around half of the tables migrated fine, but the other half, relating to string data, are failing due to errors which look a little like this - the column obviously differs from table to table. The source data is `nvarchar` in SQL, and the destination is type `varchar'

`Statement execution failed: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\xB1' for column 'AwayNote'`

Does anyone know how I can get the Migration to run successfully?

The research I have read has said to ensure server and table character sets are aligned as per the below.

[image: Server Collation]

[image: Table Collation]

I have set up my Source as SQL using the ODBC FreeTDS

[image: SQL Connection]

[image: SQL Connection 2]

The data import screen is set up like this - the check box doesn;t seem to affect things especially.

[image: Import screen]

I have MySQL setup with this too, which I have also read is important.

```
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Comment: May I ask why you're migrating to MySQL? I think you're making a mistake in the long-term... Why not Postgres instead?

Comment: My existing web host already supports MySQL and mySQL is supported pretty universally but I'm not entirely sold on it - I just want to move away from MSSQL really. I did consider PostgreSQL but I struggled to find a migration tool that I could use easily. Perhaps you know one?

Comment: Why aren't you using the SQL Server ODBC driver? FreeTDS has several issues and can't even handle parameterized queries. `nvarchar` is UTF16, not UTF8.

Comment: _"I did consider PostgreSQL but I struggled to find a migration tool"_ - Fun fact: every migration tool is awful. Have you tried using SSIS?

Comment: `I just want to move away from MSSQL really` why? Just because isn't an answer. You already found out that Unicode support in MySQL is... tricky. Features you take for granted in SQL Server and PostgreSQL just doesn't exist. They do in MariaDB but not in MySQL. For example SEQUENCE objects, the `OUTPUT` or `RETURNING` clauses.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos technically `nvarchar` is UCS-2 - unless your database's default collation is using one of the *_SC supplementary character collations at which point SQL Server's string functions support UTF-16.

Comment: `struggled to find a migration tool` MySQL or EF aren't migration tools either. Different databases have *big* differences in types, functions, behavior. MySQL is lacking many of the features found in PostgreSQL or SQL Server, so you can't just copy the SQL schema and the data. MySQL doesn't have real (physical) backups unless you *buy* an Enterprise license.

Comment: Reason for moving from MSSQL is because I want to move to a more scalable hosting platform and am cost conscious. Running on Windows and MSSQL is considerable more expensive, especially at scale.

Comment: @MatthewWarr actually ... not even clause. Not by a galactic-sized wide shot. Not that you'll ever encounter such scales - how many *million* queries are you executing right now? Have you heard what happens when you do that against a multi-processor database? Can you imagine MySQL using only a single processor because its NUMA code has bugs?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how do I utilise the SQL Server one? It isn't listed in the Migration wizard as selectabe, unless it's ODBC (native) which just won't connect to the server even with the crdentials being correct

Comment: Well I'm learning lots today :-)

Comment: @MatthewWarr you may think that the lack of SEQUENCE doesn't matter. Or the lack of RETURNING. Perhaps you intend to emulate sequences with a table with sequence names and counters. Without `OUTPUT/RETURNING` though, that requires first an UPDATE and then a READ inside a transaction, locking the table for a long time. Now imagine having 1000 concurrent connections trying to increment the sequences. And the NUMA bug kicking in ...

Comment: @MatthewWarr the scalability MySQL is know for is starting up lots of small databases on many small(er) servers. Oracle, the owner of MySQL, has *no* intention to create a database that would rival its cash cow database. That's why you'll find more features and fixes in MariaDB.

Comment: I'm no DBA and I certainly don't know the intracies of the pros and cons technically of each at this point. But it sounds to me like sticking with MSSQL may be the prudent thing to do

Comment: @MatthewWarr Our position is not "stick with MSSQL", it's "_**OH DEAR GOD ANYTHING BUT MySQL**_".

Comment: @MatthewWarr What do you mean by "I want to move to a more scalable hosting platform", exactly? (What does "scalable" even mean thesedays? It's another abused buzzword)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I thought I'd take a look at this but the complexity is a lot higher than I anticipated so I will revisit a review perhaps to Postgres in the coming months.